# Bug in package `acro`

Tags: acro, bugs

I think I found a bug in the `acro`-package which shows up with the `single`-option in use. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[single]{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{HMM}{%
    short=HMM,
    long=Hidden-Markov-Modell
}
\DeclareAcronym{HMM2}{%
    short=HMM,
    long=Hidden-Markov-Modell,
    long-plural-form=Hidden-Markov-Modells
}
\DeclareAcronym{PCA}{%
    short=PCA,
    long=Principle-Component-Analysis
}


\begin{document}
\noindent%
\acp{HMM} -- \emph{the plural form is not used}\\
\acp{HMM2} -- \emph{the plural form is used}\\
\acp{PCA} -- \emph{the plural form is used}\\
\ac{PCA}
\end{document}
```

The output of the plural form is dependant on the options you used. In the above example `HMM2` (for which a complete plural form was defined) does work though only being used once, while `HMM` doesn't. `PCA` does indeed work, because it is used more than once.

The output of the above MWE:
[image]

Output of `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    acro.sty    2017/01/22 v2.7a Typeset Acronyms
   expl3.sty    2017/04/01 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2017/04/01 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2017/04/01 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2017/04/01 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
xtemplate.sty    2017/04/01 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
zref-abspage.sty    2016/05/21 v2.26 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2016/05/21 v2.26 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
translations.sty    2017/03/05 v1.5a internationalization of LaTeX2e packages (
CN)
scrlfile.sty    2017/01/03 v3.22 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl    (english translation file `transl
ations-basic-dictionary')
 ***********
```

Comment: Seems like you should be telling the package author about this, and not us. There's an email address at the top of the documentation. (That said, "us" does actually include said package author, so he might see this anyway.)

Comment: I don't understand where is the bug.

Comment: @PaulGaborit see the text in the image, apparently it is the plural forms

Comment: Please report bugs at the official bug tracker: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/

Comment: @PaulGaborit `\acp{HMM}` should give a plural (with s at the end) but doesn't.

Comment: If I only see bugs here it is very well possible I forget about them (if I see them at all…)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report and should be reported at the official bug tracker: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/

Comment: @daleif Ok. So the first example alone (`HMM`)  is enough to show the bug...

Comment: @clemens I'm voting to close, too :) Sorry for posting here, I'll add (the same) report to your bitbucket.

Comment: @Skillmon thanks. I think I spotted the problem… I should be able to fix this and send an update to CTAN in the next few days